# AVD connect Charles

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, charles-proxy

I have configured AVD Manager like this:

[image]

and configured simulator settings:

[image]

`Charles` HTTP Proxy is 8888. But When I requesting network connection with the simulator, it still not connect to charles. I did something wrong ? Or AVD can not connect charles?

Comment: I don't think you need to configure the access point within the emulator

Answer (score 0):

As just said in a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489395/cannot-see-ios-simulator-traffic-with-charles-proxy/40616905#40616905), the simulator will likely use your computer's internet connection, unlike real devices that connect to Charlesproxy through the external http port that you specify (8888 by default).

While http traffic proxied through that port will always be recorded by Charles, recording the traffic of desktop apps like your simulator is optional. Thus the simulator's traffic will only be recorded if you check the corresponding option in the "Proxy" menu. (In Charles on Windows, the available options are "Windows Proxy" and "Firefox Proxy", not sure which are the options on a Mac.)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple as you can route your emulators traffic through terminal. The command for that will be somewhat like:-

./emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd AVD_NAME -http-proxy http://SYSTEM_IP:8888

As far as settings in emulators you have to do nothing, just a simple fiddler cert would be fine. That too you can easily push though Android Device Monitor by pushing a file in emulators internal mem.

Let me know if you face any issues i would be happy to help.

Regards,